# Can using the computer corrupt a download?

Tags: windows-8, download

I am downloading a very big file, and I would like to know if it can get corrupted only because I use the computer at the same time? Does for example removing a pen drive or an USB mouse affect the download? I know these are two processes running in parallel, but can't they affect each other?

Answer (score 2):

Except in exceptional circumstances, the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

I never seen it in my life but Win is magic OS that is capable of anything.

For example it suddenly dies and you get corrupted data. Win XP laptop killed my USB stick recently

If you have absolutely stable OS, you don't need to worry about parallel processes running. I often run several apps/threads consuming most of RAM and CPU...rarely got corrupted data unless computer suddenly crashed.